# How to get the innerText of an element with SimpleXml

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm still fairly new with SimpleXml. What I'm trying to do:

I have many xml-files, which are build about the same. My problem is that sometimes there are more nodes in my target node. Example (trying to get body):

xml-file 1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<note>
<firstname>My name is WHAT</firstname>
<lastname>My name is WHO</lastname>
<body>My name is CHIKA CHIKA Slim-Shady</body>
</note>
```

xml-file 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<note>
<firstname>My name is WHAT</firstname>
<lastname>My name is WHO</lastname>
<body><b>My name is CHIKA CHIKA Slim-Shady</b></body>
</note>
```

I can get the text in the first file with no problem:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("filename.xml");
echo $xml->note->body;
```

But when I try to do the same in the second file I get nothing back.

How can I get php to only spit out the text in a node, without regard to any additional nodes within the target node?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order for the traversal

```
echo $xml->note->body;
```

To work, your markup would need to be

```
<note>
    <note>
        <body>
        …
```

To avoid such errors, it is good practise to name the variable you `simplexml_load_file` into after the root element in the markup, e.g.

```
$note = simplexml_load_string($xml);
```

To get the "innerText" of a SimpleXmlElement you can do:

```
echo strip_tags($note->body->asXml());
```

the `asXML()` method will give you the "outerXML" which you then remove with `strip_tags`.

The alternative would be importing the node into DOM and then getting it's `nodeValue`

```
echo dom_import_simplexml($note->body)->nodeValue;
```

Comment: Wow that was fast...didn't expect to get so many answers in just a few minutes.

Comment: After tinkering for a while I finally got it to work. Many tnx!

Comment: I hate when people in such discussions just say "I got it to work" instead of posting HOW they got it to work
btw. strip_tags will remove ALL tags, including tags from the innerXml

Answer (score 2):

```
echo (string)$xml->body;
```

work for me

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add `note` It should be

First One

```
echo $xml->body;
```

Second One

```
echo $xml->body->b ;
```

Output

```
My name is CHIKA CHIKA Slim-Shady
```

Comment: while it is correct that note is wrong here, it only solves half of the problem because this will not produce the output you think it will: http://codepad.org/LiireTxn

Comment: The edit misses the question: *How can I get php to only spit out the text in a node, without regard to any additional nodes within the target node?*

Comment: `I can get the text in the first file with no problem:` contradicts that  .....  `$xml->note->body` does not work on any of the formats

Comment: `within the target node` can also be directly inside the XML node ... @Gordon